# Remove key from array if key is in another array

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays

```
array1 (
    "akey1" => "dfksjhf"
    "akey2" => "adasjkgffs"
    "akey3" => "afkjhsafshfkah"
)

array2 (
    "akey2" => "could be anything..."
)
```

I'm looking for a PHP function that I can supply the two arrays to and the following will happen:

If both arrays have an identical key (regardless of data) then remove the key from array 1 and return the remainder of array 1.

The function if ran would return:

```
array3 (
    "akey1" => "dfksjhf"
    "akey3" => "afkjhsafshfkah"
)
```

Is there a PHP function that can do this already and if not what would be the fastest and most efficient way of doing this function in PHP?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are looking for [**`array_diff_key()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php):

```
$array3 = array_diff_key($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 4):

[`array_diff_key`](http://php.net/array_diff_key) should work for you:

> Returns an array containing all the
>   entries from array1 whose keys are not
>   present in any of the other arrays.

```
$new_array = array_diff_key($array_1, $array_2);
```