# Remove blacklist keys from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an associative array of data and I have an array of keys I would like to remove from that array (while keeping the remaining keys in original order -- not that this is likely to be a constraint).

I am looking for a ***one liner*** of php to do this.
I already know how I could loop through the arrays but it seems there should be some `array_map` with `unset` or `array_filter` solution just outside of my grasp.

I have searched around for a bit but found nothing too concise.

To be clear this is the problem to do in ***one line***:

```
//have this example associative array of data
$data = array(
    'blue'   => 43,
    'red'    => 87,
    'purple' => 130,
    'green'  => 12,
    'yellow' => 31
);

//and this array of keys to remove
$bad_keys = array(
    'purple',
    'yellow'
);

//some one liner here and then $data will only have the keys blue, red, green
```

Comment: Make a function to do it: `remove_keys_from_array($array, $keys)`. And look at that, it takes up only one line!

Comment: I know but I bet there is some way to use the php functions to do it... but fair enough, it does take only one line

Comment: Related: [Remove key from array if key is in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5423640/2943403) The inverse of this question: [How do I remove keys from an array which are not in another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3970391/2943403)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

`$out =`[`array_diff_key`](http://php.net/array-diff-key)`($data,`[`array_flip`](http://php.net/array-flip)`($bad_keys));`

All I did was look through the list of [Array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) until I found the one I needed (`_diff_key`).

Comment: I had to think about this one for a mo.  The point is `$bad_keys = array(0=>'purple',1=>'yellow')` so the keys in the array_flip are 'purple','yellow'.  Hence the diff_key works.  Neat.  Thanks Kolink.

Comment: I once needed to remove by value (not keys) and I ended up with this: `$myArr = array(5, 25, 5, 30);` ... THEN ... `$myArr =& array_diff_key($myArr, array_flip(array_keys($myArr, 5)));`

Answer (score 38):

The solution is indeed [the one provided by **Niet the Dark Absol**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026799/remove-keys-from-array-within-a-blacklist-in-php#answer-11026840). I would like to provide another similar solution for anyone who is after similar thing, but this one uses a **whitelist** instead of a **blacklist**:

```
$whitelist = array( 'good_key1', 'good_key2', ... );
$output = array_intersect_key( $data, array_flip( $whitelist ) );
```

Which will preserve keys from `$whitelist` array and remove the rest.

Comment: This answer has been posted on the wrong page; it doesn't do what this page is asking for.  It is suitable (and already posted) on this earlier page: [How do I remove keys from an array which are not in another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3970391/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

This is a blacklisting function I created for associative arrays.

```
if(!function_exists('array_blacklist_assoc')){

    /**
     * Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 whose keys are not present in any of the other arrays when using their values as keys.
     * @param array $array1 The array to compare from
     * @param array $array2 The array to compare against
     * @return array $array2,... More arrays to compare against
     */

    function array_blacklist_assoc(Array $array1, Array $array2) {
        if(func_num_args() > 2){
            $args = func_get_args();
            array_shift($args);
            $array2 = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $args);
        } 
        return array_diff_key($array1, array_flip($array2));
    }
}

$sanitized_data = array_blacklist_assoc($data, $bad_keys);
```

Comment: Modern PHP affords more concise (less convoluted) syntax with the spread operator. [`function remove_blacklisted_keys(array $haystack, array ...$blacklists) {
    return array_diff_key($haystack, array_flip(array_merge(...$blacklists)));
}`](https://3v4l.org/CGuP3)

Answer (score -1):

[array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is more readable IMO.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$data = array_filter($data, function($k) use ($bad_keys) {return !in_array($k, $bad_keys);}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Comment: PHP consistently performs worse when making "values" checks (e.g. in_array(), array_search()) versus making "key" checks (e.g. array_intersect_key(), isset(), key_exists()). This answer is not likely to outperform other, earlier answers on this page. This answer will make N calls of in_array(), but other answers on this page do not make iterated function calls.  A Stack Overflow answer must never contain `Hope this helps` -- it is irrelevant to the page; no signoffs or esignatures. Modern concise code: `$data = array_filter($data, fn($k) => !in_array($k, $bad_keys), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);`